# Different ValueError each time I run

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a beginner to ML with Python Pandas and SciKit and this is my first project. I have a dataset containing some known information about the passengers aboard the Titanic in a CSV file with 893 lines that looks like this:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",0,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",1,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",1,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",1,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
```

Based on this data, I'm trying to build a program that given similar data, can tell me whether the passenger would have survived. My code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
X = data.drop(columns=["PassengerId", "Survived", "Name"])
print(X)
y = data["Survived"]
print(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.9)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(X_test)
print(predictions)

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(score*100, "% accuracy.")
```

However, I keep running into the same ValueError, with a random line within the dataset. Something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1474, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 1009, in fit
    super()._fit(
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 252, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 645, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_X_params)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 997, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 521, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2150, in __array__
    arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Hassab, Mr. Hammad'
```

Or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1474, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 1009, in fit
    super()._fit(
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 252, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 645, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_X_params)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 997, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 521, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/runner/MachineLearning1/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2150, in __array__
    arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Tornquist, Mr. William Henry'
```

Where in both cases, the error is the same, but the name that the error is attributed to is different each and every time.

What I'm expecting is the data given and the predictions both printed in the console as well as the accuracy. My question is, why am I getting this error? (I've deduced the randomness is due to no `random_state` parameter being specified)

Comment: Is the name of the passenger relevant  for prediction?  It looks to me that non-numerical features such as Sex, Ticket, Cabin, Embarked are not [encoded for your classifier](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-encoding-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-implementation-dbf933e64aa?gi=cd1a5057c89e)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule thats true. I've changed the sex column to be either 0 or 1. do I have to do the same for all other non-numerical features or encode them?

Comment: Yes,  you have to do so.

Comment: Note, it's a different line each time because train_test_split is stochastic, so you will have different lines in your training/test set each time.